# Z3 BitVector bug?

Tags: z3, ml

There seems to be a bug in the bitvector theory of Z3. Creating a bitvector constant using Expr.mk_numeral_string in ML interface and then reading the expression using BitVector.get_string or BitVector.get_int results in amismatch.

Here are the details:

`let create_bv_const ctx bv_str width = 
   let bv_sort = BitVector.mk_sort ctx width in
   Expr.mk_numeral_string ctx bv_str bv_sort`

Now

```
let bv1 = create_bv_const ctx "1111" 4.
```

Reading bv1 using `Expr.to_string` returns "7" when it should be "15".

Similar error occurs when using `Expr.to_int`. If

`let bv1 = create_bv_const ctx "0010" 4`

reading bv1 should give "2" but Z3 returns "10". "0011" gives "11" when it should be "3". I tried with widths 5, 8 bit vectors and there were similar issues. But with width <=3 bitvectors it works fine.

I tried an older version of Z3 (v. 4) and there is similar problem there as well.

Hope I am not missing something. I want to create formulas with bitvector variables and consts and read out the bitvector values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1111 mod 16 = 7, so this is correct. Note that argument 1111 is read as a decimal, not binary number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!